# transpose 2 rows to one row

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am displaying below data in a grid.

```
ID     Name   Address
-----------------------------------------
1      Mike     100, Francis Dr, PA
1      Mike      2, Richmond Street, PA
2      John     45, Francis Dr, PA
2      John     55, Richmond Street, PA
3      Peter    23, Castle Street, PA
```

How can I transpose address2 as a new column in Telerik grid or in linq query and display like this -

```
ID     Name   Home-Address            Office-Address
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      Mike     100, Francis Dr, PA      2, Richmond Street, PA
2      John     45, Francis Dr, PA        55, Richmond Street, PA
3      Peter    23, Castle Street, PA
```

Comment: How do you know which address is home or office? (You can't use the order in a relational DB table.) Once you have that, you can do it with a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Where is the data coming from?

Comment: Actually scenario is different. We can just consider it as Address1 and Address1. Thanks

Comment: Data is coming from MS SQL database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that your first address as home-address and second address as office-address and also there is a direct table. In that case write a SP and assign it to telerik data source

```
select t1.ID, t1.Name, t1.Home_Address, t2.Office_Address
(select ID,Name,Address as Home_Address 
from
(select ID,Name,Address,row_number() over (partition by ID Order by ID) rnum
from table_name) a
where a.rnum=1 ) t1 
left join
(select ID,Name,Address as Office_Address from
(select ID,Name,Address,row_number() over (partition by ID Order by ID) rnum
from table_name) b 
where b.rnum=2) t2
on t1.ID=t2.ID
```

Comment: He didn't ask for SQL and you are missing `()` in your `row_number()`

Comment: also you really want to use a `WITH` or temp table here, since row_number() could change between the two -- ID is not unique.

Comment: Thanks SNathan. I am getting expected result from your query. But we are not using SP's in the project. I can use view but cant use this script in view. Any other way of doing this? Thanks

Comment: SNathan, The query works fine in view. It was showing some error with pane criteria and diagram.

Comment: user1979284 - Welcome. As Hogan told, please try to use WITH or TEMP table for more reliable solution (Or order by Address instead of order by ID - not efficient one).

Answer (score 1):

This shows you how to do it with a Addr1 and Addr2, as the comments say above you can't know the order as you present the data so you can't know which is work and which is home.

```
void Main()
{
   List<record> data = new List<record> {
    new record() { ID = 1, Name = "Mike", Address = "100, Francis Dr, PA" },
    new record() { ID = 1, Name = "Mike", Address = "2, Richmond Street, PA" },
    new record() { ID = 2, Name = "John", Address = "45, Francis Dr, PA" },
    new record() { ID = 2, Name = "John", Address = "55, Richmond Street, PA" },
    new record() { ID = 3, Name = "Peter", Address = "23, Castle Street, PA" } };

   var result
     = data.GroupBy((x) => new { ID =x.ID, Name = x.Name })
        .Select((x) => 
           new { ID = x.Key.ID,
                 Name = x.Key.Name,
                 Addr1 = x.Take(1).Select((z) => z.Address).FirstOrDefault(),
                 Addr2 = x.Skip(1).Select((z) => z.Address).FirstOrDefault()});

}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class record
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Indented to fit nice on the thin column.

Results from LinqPad:

[image]

You could also make a delimited list by replacing the Addr lines with this:

```
 Alist = string.Join("||",x.Select((z) => z.Address))});
```

Which would look like this:

[image]

Comment: I am getting an error - x is undeclared. I am using Vb.net and Linq. Sorry I am new to vb and linq. Thanks Hogan.

Comment: Exact error msg - Error 319 'x' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: @user1979284 - you have a typo then, the code above compiles and runs just fine on LinqPad.  If you can't see the typo post the code or email it to me (email addr on my profile.)